# Android Auto custom apps - Official

Tags: android, android-developer-api, google-developers-console, android-auto

I want to create a Custom Android auto app without doing driver distraction.
I went through a lot of blogs and sites and I saw that there used to be custom apps that were blocked since the version 3.0. The developers of those custom apps were using an unofficial Android Auto SDK (https://github.com/martoreto/aauto-sdk) which has been removed.

Is there a way to build a custom Android auto app which is completely legal?

Is there any open source SDK-for-auto that is still available?

(Note: Please don't mark this as duplicate as I went through the other questions & solutions and tried everything but none worked so far)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn’t any open source version of the SDK that is supported by Google. The Android Auto FullScreen SDK to build custom apps is only available for use by [Automotive OEM partners](https://designguidelines.withgoogle.com/android-auto/custom-apps/custom-app-anatomy.html#) that have signed agreements with Google. So even if you can find one, if you’re not a signed partner, the app still won’t be able to be published to the Play store.

The [Android Auto public templates](https://developer.android.com/training/auto/start/) that are available for developers to build off of, support either media or messaging only.

Comment: Thanks for the information. How could i contact these Automotive OEM partners ? I couldn;t find any contact-support from their website.

Comment: Sorry, i don't have any info on how to contact the automotive partners directly either. I have a feeling though that a part of their agreement would include not sharing the sdk.

Comment: Thanks for the information. How could contact these Automotive OEM partners ?