# Custom Application - Android Auto

Tags: google-maps, auto, google-assistant-sdk, android-auto, custom-application

I would like to know how could I create a custom application for Android Auto. Nowadays, I know I can create “media” and “notification” Android Auto apps, but I would like to have a custom app (with a custom service), because I would like to create a google assistant flow and modify the map.

GOOGLE ASSISTANT NEW FLOW

I would like to get custom responses for some request by voice, because I would like to ask an appointment by Google Assistant. I have just seen an Android Auto notification app. With those methods I can send and replay some message, but it’s not a new or custom Google Assistant dialog. How could I create a new app with a new google assistant voice flow.

Please, if somebody have a custom Android Auto app example to learn it, I would appreciate so much! :D

MAPS

In addition, I don’t know if I could edit Google Maps for remark some custom places in the map from my Android app, or if it’s necessary create my own map in my application. I’m not sure if when I ask to Google Assistant it’ll works my custom Google Map or it will show me the standard Google Maps (without my remarkable places).

I NEED CREATE SOMETHING LIKE THIS —>
￼[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7vI1.png)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 5):

That's an interesting question.

Based on https://designguidelines.withgoogle.com/android-auto/custom-apps/custom-app-anatomy.html it is supposed to be possible to develop custom applications.

But when you create a project in Android Studio it is only possible to create *messaging* and *audio* applications (at least those are the public templates that are offered).

I have been looking about that and I have found some interesting answers from people answering the same question:

- [Android Auto custom apps - Official](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50514109/android-auto-custom-apps-official)
- [Build Custom App for Android Auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42017306/build-custom-app-for-android-auto)
- [Can I make any apps for Android Auto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35455604/can-i-make-any-apps-for-android-auto)
- https://support.google.com/androidauto/thread/2998734?hl=en

So based on this answers it is not possible to develop *custom applications* unless that you have the another SDK to do that. And if you get that SDK you need to be a Google partner to publish them.

If anyone knows another way to develop custom applications or how to get that *another SDK*, it would be great to know.